# non linear equations solving methods?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

I need to find $l_{2}$ and $\theta$ numerically by solving below equations. How could I do that? At least do i have some iterative way of finding those two unknowns. All others parameters are constants.

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\mu_{0}\sin(\theta-\theta_{0})}{\sqrt{l_{2}^2 +\mu_{0}l_{2}\cos(\theta-\theta_{0}) +\lambda_{0}}} + \frac{\mu_{1}\sin(\theta-\theta_{1})}{\sqrt{l_{2}^2 +\mu_{1}l_{2}\cos(\theta-\theta_{1}) +\lambda_{1}}} =0 \\
\frac{2l_{2}+\beta_{0}+\mu_{0}\cos(\theta-\theta_{0})}{\sqrt{l_{2}^2 +\mu_{0}l_{2}\cos(\theta-\theta_{0}) +\lambda_{0}}}+ \frac{2l_{2}+\beta_{1}+\mu_{1}\cos(\theta-\theta_{1})}{\sqrt{l_{2}^2 +\mu_{1}l_{2}\cos(\theta-\theta_{1}) +\lambda_{1}}} =\frac{-2}{1+Vr^{l_{2}/D}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Your system is like $\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}\land \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial l_2}+\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial l_2}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial l_2}$. Is this how you got it?

Comment: actually it looks like  $\bigg(\frac{\partial f_{0}}{\partial \theta} +\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \theta}\bigg)= 0$ and $\bigg(\frac{\partial f_{0}}{\partial l_{2}} +\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial l_{2}}\bigg)=\frac{-1}{1+Vr^{l_{2}/D}}$

Answer (score 1):

Try [multivariate Newton Raphson method](http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Math_Topics/Multivariate_Newton-Raphson.htm)

Comment: Is this method easy? it is hard to find the derivatives.

Comment: Ask any computer algebra system, i.e. [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) or http://www.WolframAlpha.com.